# Google plus one button with recommendation feature in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I have implemented google plus one button in my code for the recommendation feature(like that of "Like" in facebook).but when i run my code it shows a dilog box .
The share option is not working properly since it post some blank text on the wall.So it is useless.

I only want the recommendation option no need of sharing.My requirement is that :-
When i presses the button it will add recommendation and presses twice it will undo the recommendation.
    in onCreate():-

```
    PlusOneButton mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) v.findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);    
 @Override    
public void onResume() {   
    super.onResume();  
    mPlusOneButton.initialize(APPURL, REQUEST_CODE);  
}
```

and in the xml:-

```
   <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton   xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
            android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            plus:annotation="bubble"
            plus:size="standard" />
```

Can someone help me to find the answer.